# "All connectors hub" for an another room PC

Tags: usb, desktop, hub, display-port

Currently planning an new high-end PC with high-end graphics card, 4x hdd, etc...

Want **0dB** (silent) even under the high load, so no vent noise even from the PSU. For me the easy solution is: putting the PC into the another adjacent room.

Now the question: Looking for a piece of hardware which should contain:

- power & reset buttons
- plenty of USB-2/3 connectors
- at least one usb-c connector
- 3x display-port connector

Because one picture worth 1000 words (and my english isn't the best anyway) here is one:

[image]

In short: Looking for a device (an extender) which will contain all of the connectors and buttons that the PC (in the another room) has. (distance approx. 3m).